# LLDB disassembler not working, using command terminal,on mac el captain?

Tags: disassembly, disassemblers

I have created simple code to test using lldb . This is the first time i am using lldb and i am familiar with gdb. while i am trying to disassemble the unix executable file its not working any commands i should use . Or i should try other , if so can you provide me a list of disassembler,decompiler and debugger for unix and windows 64bit processors which supports scripting too. I have searched for them but could't find. can you suggest me list of good disassemblers.

Comment: "not working" is not very helpful description. What exactly are you trying and what (error) messages do you get?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying, exactly? Here are some disassemble commands for use within LLDB:

`disassemble --frame`: Disassemble the currently running function.

`disassemble -a 0x1234`: Disassemble the function containing the address `0x1234`

`disassemble -n _foo`: Disassemble the function called "`_foo`"

Try `help disassemble` to learn more.

As for a list of good disassemblers on various platforms, it depends whether you have a lot of disposable income or not. IDA Pro is the best but it costs around $1000. If that's prohibitive, Google can help you find lists of free and cheap tools.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Capstone (www.capstone-engine.org), which is widely used and cross-platform/cross-architecture. It has a very good Python binding, so you can write your script as LLDB plugin or GDB plugin.